# Unir data frames en uno sólo en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero unir estos data frames para luego poder trabajar haciendo regresiones entre variables de los distintos data frames, ¿Cómo puedo unir todos los data frames en uno solo ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library("tidyverse")
library(caret)
data_p <- read_excel("C:/Users/x/Desktop/regresion.xlsx")
data_t_dic <- read_excel("C:/Users/x/Desktop/temperatura_mensual.xlsx", 
                                  sheet = "dic")
data_t_ene <- read_excel("C:/Users/x/Desktop/temperatura_mensual.xlsx", 
                         sheet = "ene")

data_t_feb <- read_excel("C:/Users/x/desktop/temperatura_mensual.xlsx", 
                         sheet = "feb")

df_p <- data.frame(data_p)
df_t_d <- data.frame(data_t_dic)
df_t_e <- data.frame(data_t_ene)
df_t_f <- data.frame(data_t_feb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estás usando `tidyverse/dplyr` puedes aprovechar el verbo [`union_all()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/setops.html), siempre que cada `data.frame`tenga la misma estructura:

```
library("tidyverse")

data_p %>%
  union_all(data_t_dic) %>% 
  union_all(data_t_ene) %>% 
  union_all(data_t_feb) -> data_completa
```

En R base tampoco es complejo, si usamos `rbind()`

```
data_completa <- rbind(data_p, rbind(data_t_dic, rbind(data_t_ene, data_t_ene)))
```

Answer (score 2):

La función ´bind_rows()´ de ´dplyr´ hace exactamente eso.

Acepta como argumento nombres de data.frame separados por comas, en tu caso sería

```
bind_rows(data_p, data_t_dic, data_t_ene, data_t_feb)
```

Una ventaja (o desventaja, dependiendo del caso particular de uso) es que ´bind_rows()´ producirá un data.frame unido aún si el orden de las columnas no es el mismo, ya que la unión se hace por nombres y no por posiciones. Inclusive cuando no todos los df tienen las mismas columnas produce un output rellenando con ´NA´ en los data.frame que no tienen una columna.

Otra característica interesante es que podemos pasarlo los nombres o directamente una lista que contenga data.frames

Ejemplo:

```
lista_df <- list(primero = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5]), 
                 segundo = data.frame(a = 6:10, c = TRUE))
bind_rows(lista_df)

a    b    c
1    a   NA
2    b   NA
3    c   NA
4    d   NA
5    e   NA
6  <NA> TRUE
7  <NA> TRUE
8  <NA> TRUE
9  <NA> TRUE
10 <NA> TRUE
```

Me ha servido muchísimo trabajando con bases de datos ligeramente distintas.